# Find the global and local extrema in set

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier, maxima-minima, hessian-matrix

> Given the function:  $f(x, y) = x^2 - y^2$
>
> Determine the local and global extrema for f in the set $M = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R^2}\  |\  y + e^{-x^2} -1 =0\}$

I know about Lagrange Multipliers, but we didn't cover them  yet, so I'm wondering if there's any way to do this without using them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need Lagrange multipliers here. Just define$$\varphi(x)=x^2-\left(1-e^{-x^2}\right)^2.$$This is a differentiable function from $\mathbb R$ into itself. Use the standard methods for finding its local extrema. You will get that it has no local maximum and that its only local minimum is located at $0$.